# Creating series from series in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data of this form (simplified, but assume 20 columns between Admin and Mining):

```
Date,Series,Admin,Mining,CPI
1990,Ordinary Time Earnings,20,30,96
1991,Ordinary Time Earnings,22,33,100
1990,Total Earnings,25,38,96
1991,Total Earnings,29,43,100
```

Which I separate out into two series like this:

```
d3.csv("avgearnings_v1_1.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  OrdinaryTimeEarnings = data
    .filter(function(d) {
        if(d.Series == 'Ordinary Time Earnings')
            return d;
    });
  TotalEarnings = data
    .filter(function(d) {
        if(d.Series == "Total Earnings")
            return d;
    });
```

And can get that to display on a graph without any issue. What I want to do next is create two more series:

```
OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal = OrdinaryTimeEarnings;
TotalEarningsReal = TotalEarnings;
```

And then recalculate those new series. Basically:

- For any column that is not Date/Series/CPI
- Take the CPI value for that year
- Individually divide each of the Mining-Admin columns by the CPI and multiply by 100.
- So: New Value = ([Old Value]/[CPI])*100

My code is terrible but I can get the correct values using this:

```
OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal
    .forEach(function (z,i) {
        var CPI = z["CPI"];
        d3.map(z, function(b) {return b;})
            .forEach(function (c) {
                if(c !== "Date" && c !== "Series" && c !== "CPI" ) 
                    OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal[i][c] = ((z[c])/(CPI))*100;       
            });
    });
```

But, when I do this it is somehow also updating the original OrdinaryTimeEarnings series, such that they equal each other and the original data in OrdinaryTimeEarnings is lost.

I'm not sure whether it's the fact I'm using the bare object (while iterating within it, eek!) or that the code above is actually changing the values in the original data object (and all 4 of the series I've created after are just references to it).

Either way, I can't work it out! I've tried a fair few different syntax forms but can't work it out. Help would be greatly appreciated to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed use this code to "duplicate" your arrays:

```
OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal = OrdinaryTimeEarnings;
TotalEarningsReal = TotalEarnings;
```

then you mentioned it right, when you said that they reference the same object. In JavaScript, arrays are mutable, and using the code above you just created 2 new variables with a reference to the existing array in the memory.

In order to deep clone your array of objects, use this method:

```
OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(OrdinaryTimeEarnings));
TotalEarningsReal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TotalEarnings));
```

This will create duplicates of the array and assign them to the new variables, so that when you'll edit them, the initial arrays will remain unaffected.

Now, regarding your code, it's a bit too complex. If I understood correctly what are you trying to achieve, you could simplify it as follows:

```
OrdinaryTimeEarningsReal
.forEach(function (z,i) {
    for (var c in z) {
        if (z.hasOwnProperty(c) && c !== "Date" && c !== "Series" && c !== "CPI" ) 
            z[c] = z[c] / z.CPI * 100;       
    });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've been working on a solution for this also, and realised that I needed to add the slice(). I have added it yet the original data seems to be getting overwritten : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/9ywLytjf/3/

Comment: @thatOneGuy Oh, it happens because `.slice()` still copies object references into the new array. The array itself has points to another object in the memory, but the component objects still point to the same place. Instead of `slice`, use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`. Here is a working [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/dot07ggy/) of your fiddle.

Comment: @thatOneGuy I've updated my answer with the new method of deep cloning the data.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly there and I like the shortened code, very elegant. About slice() though, I've borrowed thatOneGuy's fiddle and tried to implement it, but seems to have the same issue with the two series equalling each other. https://jsfiddle.net/crimsonbinome22/7sxrLky3/

Comment: @crimsonbinome22 [This](https://jsfiddle.net/7sxrLky3/1/) is the updated fiddle with the working solution (using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` )

Comment: Bingo, that's fixed it. Thanks both!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly :

```
data.forEach(function(d) { 
  for (var key in d) {
    if (key !== 'Date' && key !== 'Series' && key !== 'CPI') {
      d['new' + key] = (d[key] / d.CPI) * 100;
    }
  }
})
console.log(data)
```

I have added `new` onto the new attributes so the new `admin` value is `newAdmin`

Implemented fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/9ywLytjf/

Comment: Just realised your problem, the other answer is about the slice() is the way to go