# array1.splice(1,1) is removing data from array2 which I have created using array1.slice(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, d3.js

I have JSON data, and I have converted that data into an array of objects and have assigned that array into an another array using the .slice(0) method.

When I am trying to remove some element from the assigned array it is removing the same element from the original element.

But I don't want to change my original array at any point of time.

```
var values = [
  {
    "timeId":"201501010100",
    "Week1Volume": 2454721,
    "Week2Volume": 7017731,
    "Week3Volume": 5656528,
    "Week4Volume": 2472223
  },
  {
    "timeId":"201501010200",
    "Week1Volume": 2454721,
    "Week2Volume": 7017731,
    "Week3Volume": 5656528,
    "Week4Volume": 2472223
  },
  {
    "timeId":"201501010300",
    "Week1Volume": 1999120,
    "Week2Volume": 5355235,
    "Week3Volume": 5120254,
    "Week4Volume": 2607672
  }]; // This is my JSON data

var weekNames = d3.keys(values[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "timeId" && key!== "weeksVolume";});;

values.forEach(function(d) {
  d.weeksVolume = weekNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
}); // original array

var data = values.slice(0); // Data is my new array

function removeFromSecondArray(){

    // Here I am removing the first object of weekVolumes from each object of the array
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.weeksVolume.splice(1,1);
        });
};
```

But after execution of above function 1st element of "values" also got removed.

Comment: Take a look at the answer in this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006725/creating-series-from-series-in-d3/37007424#37007424 it may help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is your problem:

When you are copying the JSON object you are creating the reference to an old object. So, any operation done on one reference will be performed on both objects. 
So you should apply a deep copy here like this and then apply the further manipulations.

```
  var newObj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
```

I hope this will help you. This is a deep copy. It will not create the reference.